# Ipad/Iphone like scrolling

Tags: javascript, ipad, scroll, smooth-scrolling

Have any of you seen like a javascript library that allows fluid div scrolling.  I kind of want to do something like the scroll bars in google wave...but maybe less annoying.  I happen to love them but it doesn't seem like they're getting that good of a review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe iScroll might be of help. It provides a way to scroll content inside a fixed width/height element.

You can find more information on it here:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: Awesome, that's 100% what I was looking for thanks.  I really did not want to go to sproutcore or jqtouch.  This is dead on =P

Comment: iScroll is really sweet, UNLESS the scrolling region has form elements (e.g., text inputs). In that case, it doesn't work very well at all. Matteo has acknowleged the problem and is working on it in version 4, but for now, getting it to work with form elements involves quite a bit of hacking. http://code.google.com/p/iscroll-js/issues/list